# Connect to console app running as a system task on Windows server

Tags: scheduled-tasks, console-application, wrapper, windows-server-2012-r2, nssm

I run several game servers on a single [windows-server-2012-r2](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012-r2). Many of the game servers run as [console-application](/questions/tagged/console-application). I have created [scheduled-tasks](/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks) to run each on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) startup even if I'm not logged on. I would like to be able to attach to the consoles of those apps when logged on to the server, similar to what can be done in [linux](/questions/tagged/linux). Perhaps I'm going about this in the wrong way. Is there a way to attach to console apps running as tasks? Is there a software tool that accommodates this sort of thing?

**Update:**
Been searching high and low for a solution but haven't found anything yet. Have decided to write a [wrapper](/questions/tagged/wrapper) for console app that will redirect Stdin, Stdout and Stderr of a process to a Telnet connection. Will use [nssm](/questions/tagged/nssm) to run the wrapper as a [service](/questions/tagged/service).

Comment: I think the typical approach for your scenario would be windows services instead of console application. You can then use any number IPC techniques to communicate with that service. The Windows Service feature itself offers a lot of the most common features needed for long-running executables.

Comment: @Gulliaume - thanks for the comment. I agree but the game servers are actually console apps. Most are _exe_ wrappers around Java apps. I run most of the servers as startup tasks for now since they are running on a leased dedicated server and I access it via RDP. To gracefully shut them down I have to open each game client and send _console commands_ to save the game and then quit the server. So, after a lot of consideration, I'd prefer to connect to them remotely using a Telnet client wherein I can access each game's original console. I will still leverage Windows service features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I produced a solution: https://github.com/ccourson/Banjo

Banjo will launch a specified console application and route its streams to and from a telnet connection.

Pull requests welcome.